# I want to return Boolean after firebase code is executed

Tags: ios, swift, return

I'm retrieving data from Firebase Google. I'm checking the data i received is expire or not.

```
func checkBought(movieName : String) -> Bool{

    var yesOrNo = false

    boughtRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snap) in

        if snap.value![movieName]! != nil {
            if self.timestamp > snap.value![movieName]! as! Double {
                //expire
                print("expire")
                yesOrNo = false
            } else {
                //not expire
                print("not expire")
                yesOrNo = true
            }
        } else {
            //not bought yet
            print("No movie")
            yesOrNo = false

        }
    })

    return yesOrNo
}
```

Now, the return statement is returning before the firebase code is executed and change the value of yesOrNo.

Comment: You are not using the blocks as intended, the return statement should be INSIDE your block. The way it works now is that it will return false before the completion block is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic:

**You cannot return anything from a method which contains an asynchronous task**

You need a completion block, simply

```
func checkBought(movieName : String, completion:(Bool) -> Void) {

    boughtRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snap) in

    if snap.value![movieName]! != nil {
      if self.timestamp > snap.value![movieName]! as! Double {
        //expire
        print("expire")
        completion(false)
      } else {
        //not expire
        print("not expire")
        completion(true)
      }
    } else {
      //not bought yet
      print("No movie")
      completion(false)

    }
  })
}
```

Or easier

```
func checkBought(movieName : String, completion:(Bool) -> Void) {
  boughtRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snap) in
    if let movieStamp = snap.value![movieName] as? Double where self.timestamp <= movieStamp {
      //not expire
      print("not expire")
      completion(true)
    } else {
      // expire or not bought yet
      print("expire or no movie")
      completion(false)
    }
  })
}
```

And call it with

```
checkBought("Foo") { flag in
   print(flag)
}
```